# How to get attachment from email channel?

Tags: botframework

Is it possible to get the the email attachment using MSBot email channel, I tried searching bit didn't find any reference for this.

Please let me know if anyone have reference/solution for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60570128/receive-and-send-attachment-as-email-within-microsoft-bot-framework

Comment: @ranusharao, the above link, talks about sending mail with attachments, it's not related to the email channel.